# RestSharp authentication with Api Id and Api Key

Tags: c#, api, rest, restsharp

I have to call a restful API, but the only details I have are an API ID and an API key.

I am trying to use Restsharp library code like this.

```
  var client = new RestClient("https://xxxxxxx");
  client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("xxxxx", "yyyyyy");
```

I get a 401 authorization required error.

Could you please point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the solution that i came up with.

this returns the client object

```
private RestClient InitializeAndGetClient()
        {
            var cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
            var client = new RestClient("https://xxxxxxx")
            {
                Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("xxIDxx", "xxKeyxx"),
                CookieContainer = cookieJar
            };

            return client;
        }
```

and you can use the method like

```
            var client = InitializeAndGetClient();
            var request = new RestRequest("report/transaction", Method.GET);

            request.AddParameter("option", "value");



            //Run once to get cookie.
            var response = client.Execute(request);

            //Run second time to get actual data
            response = client.Execute(request);
```

Hope this helps you.

Prakash.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old but this is partial to what I needed:

```
        var cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
        var client = new RestClient("https://xxxxxxx")
        {
            Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("[username]", "[password]"),
            CookieContainer = cookieJar
        };
```

Then right after I made the request object I had to add the API_KEY header:

```
            var request = new RestRequest("[api]/[method]"); // this will be unique to what you are connecting to
            request.AddHeader("API_KEY", "[THIS IS THE API KEY]");
```